# Azure service buss for UWP application

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, azureservicebus, servicebus

I am trying to integrate Azure service bus in my UWP application but it is not compatible. Any solution?

[image]

[image]

**Update**

If i create a project targeting last windows version i can install it but cant run the project

`'Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.' App15`

Comment: Try https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/

Comment: @PeterBons It is the same thing no difference

Comment: What is the output of the package maneger console?

Comment: @PeterBons same as above

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` [supports UWP](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/50) 10.0.16299 and up as it [supports `netstandard2.0`](http://immo.landwerth.net/netstandard-versions/). There's something on the project level.

If you believe there's an issue with the package, [raise an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues) in the client repository.

Comment: It is just a new app i created nothing inside, blank UWP app so what can be wrong on project level?

Comment: If i target last windows build, i can install service buss but i cant runn project 
 "Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.' App15"

Comment: I saw you've raised a GitHub issue. Looks like dependencies are conflicting. Let's see what the team says.